# how to differentiate this copy to clipboard, for buttons one and two respectively? because when I click on both buttons, the same number is copied

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<script>
  function copyText() {

    /* Copy text into clipboard */
    navigator.clipboard.writeText("12345");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText("54321");
  }
</script>

<p id="p1">
  <div class="enabled-left-icon-4-9z5"><button onclick="copyText()">copied</button></div>
</p>
<p id="p2">
  <div class="enabled-left-icon-5-MqF"><button onclick="copyText()">copied</button></div>
</p>
```

---

```
<script>
  function copyText() {

    /* Copy text into clipboard */
    p1 navigator.clipboard.writeText("12345");
    p2 navigator.clipboard.writeText("54321");
  }
</script>

<p id="p1">
  <div class="enabled-left-icon-4-9z5"><button onclick="copyText()">copied</button></div>
</p>
<p id="p2">
  <div class="enabled-left-icon-5-MqF"><button onclick="copyText()">copied</button></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the required value

```
function copyText(textToCopy) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy);
}

<button onclick="copyText('12345')">Copy 12345</button>
<button onclick="copyText('54321')">Copy 54321</button>
```